# QR Code Scanner and Generator

Tags: android-studio, generator, qr-code, barcode-scanner

So I was following the code from this github:
https://github.com/prudhvirajkumar10/QR-Code/

When I tried to install the apk from my phone, it won't open the app.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I am trying to install, it is 2:15am at my end. I have to go to bed now. I will get back to you morrow morning.

Comment: the app installed at my end fine. we will discuss tomorrow, sorry

Comment: you should check my question about the 'clickable result'

Comment: @tannitanna hi tannitanna, It seems I can't ask another questions on this site. Since I'm too dumb asking a stupid question. Can you help me with my problem please? Its the scanner result and the downloadable or save QR Code from the generator? Please help me. I really need this to get done if I want to graduate :(

Comment: Share me your email id. Actually I am travelling and I am not carrying any laptop, I will see how best I can help you.

Comment: @tannitanna Its ricardoseikka@gmail.com. Thank you so much tannitanna :(

Comment: @tannitanna Can you share your email id too? So I can send you my questions that I want to ask about.

Comment: I have sent a test email, please check your inbox

Comment: @tannitanna Okay, please check my replied sir. Thank you again. I never being help so much like this before :(